# How to get other user's mention timeline of twitter with twitter4j api?

Tags: twitter4j

I'm struggling to get other user's mention timeline with twitter4j api. I could figure out that it's possible only to get other user's UserTimeline. It seems that there is no way to get other user's mention timeline
(I found that [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html)  - lookup "Interface TimelinesResources")

Is there way to get other user's mention timeline ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the MentionsTimeline using getMentionsTimeline() method of [TimelineResources](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html) as a link you mentioned with some limitations of number of tweets returned.

Find below example of the example which will give you MentionsTimeline.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
try {
       User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
       List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentionsTimeline();
       System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s mentions.");
       for (Status status : statuses) {
           System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
       }
} catch (TwitterException te) {
       te.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
       System.exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getUserTimeline()](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html#getUserTimeline-java.lang.String-) method of [Twitter](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html) class.

References:
1. [http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html)
2. http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API doesn't have an endpoint for viewing other users mentions (the [statuses/mentions_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) returns only the mentions of the authenticated user).

You should use the [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), using as the query string the @screen_name of the user you want to get the mentions. Please note that the Twitter Search API may not return all mentions for a given user (it says that "the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness").

So, using Twitter4j, you can get @NASA mentions using the following

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
try {
    Query query = new Query("@NASA");
    QueryResult result;
    do {
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        }
    } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
    System.exit(0);
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
}
```